# Creation a mobile version of a prestashop website

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.5, prestashop-1.6

I have a prestashop website version 1.4 I want to create this website version  mobile , 
please if you have any advice to start or any tutoriel because i search in the net and i don't found somthing useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade to `prestashop 1.6` with the `OneClickUpgrade` module, and use the default `prestashop 1.6` skin. I've made the upgrade this way from 1.4 to 1.6 without any problem.

The default 1.6 skin is responsive, so your website will work with mobiles, tablets and computers.

Then adapt the default skin to your actual website colors.

Before doing it, **backup your database and your files**.

I think it is easier to upgrade than to create your own responsive skin.